# how to get depress effect on a button/image in Appcelerator

Tags: ios, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I have the following code, how can I make the "press" "depress" effect on an image in appcelartor..

there is action applied to each - but I am unable to find the best way to get depress effect.

code:

```
var win = Titanium.UI.createWindow({  
    backgroundColor:"white",
});

var scrollview = Ti.UI.createScrollView({
  showVerticalScrollIndicator: true,
  showHorizontalScrollIndicator: true,
  layout: 'vertical' 
  });


var imga = Titanium.UI.createImageView ({
    image: "/png/a.png",
    top: 0
    });

var imgb = Titanium.UI.createImageView ({
    image: "/png/b.png",
    top: 10
    });

var imgc = Titanium.UI.createImageView ({
    image: "/png/c.png",
    top: 10
    });


scrollview.add(imga,imgb,imgc);     
win.add(scrollview);
win.open () ;
```

thanks

Comment: Can you explain what is "press" and "depress" effect ?

Comment: like when you click / touch a button and it goes down ? like 3d effect. like (http://www.paulund.co.uk/playground/demo/css_3d_push_button)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The selected / unSelected effect is handle by the platform and it's automatic with Button. However, it's not with ImageView. So you have to do it manually and listen to the `touchstart` http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.ImageView-event-touchstart and `touchend` http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.ImageView-event-touchend events.

In the touchstart event, you can set another image by example to simulate selected effect, like this :

```
var imga = Titanium.UI.createImageView ({
    image: "/png/a.png",
    top: 0
 });

 imga.addEventListener('touchstart', function(e){
    e.source.image = "png/a-selected.png";
 });

  imga.addEventListener('touchend', function(e){
    e.source.image = "png/a.png";
 });
```

Comment: This is a little different; no ? I want to be able do a press like - with a shadow.. not change image. as I have several images - that means - I have to double the number of images. can I not have a shadow option to mimic 3d effect.  your code swaps the button. is that only option ?

Comment: Well, this 3D effect it's not a mobile behavior. I suggest you to use a `Button` http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.Button instead of ImageView (to have the press effect without adding a code). On Android, you can set shadow property : http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.Button-property-shadowOffset

Comment: hi @thomas-lemaitre, can you help me figure out how i can place a transparent (say @ 80%) on top of the original image - onclick ? that way - I can make it seem like an action happened when I clicked ?  the currrent code replaces the buttons..